# How to debug Elixir application which running with docker?

Tags: debugging, docker, docker-compose, elixir, phoenix-framework

Use this way can debug:

```
require IEx;

defmodule Example do
  def double_sum(x, y) do
    IEx.pry
    hard_work(x, y)
  end

  defp hard_work(x, y) do
    2 * (x + y)
  end
end
```

But if running the program in docker with other `microservices` such as db, cache, worker by `docker-compose`, it won't stop even set the `breakpoint`.

Comment: How about `remote console`? You can execute it like `iex -S mix`.

Comment: In addition to `require IEx`, you also need to launch your application using `iex -S mix` or `iex -S mix phx.server`. Did you do that? Could you share your `docker-compose` file?

Comment: @YongHaoHu Thank you. 我的项目包含几个不同的项目，有rails的有phoenix的，用docker-compose把所有都包在一起启动，单独启动phoenix的不容易。

Comment: @KevinJohnson Thank you. My project contains several different projects. For example, rails, phoenix, and others. Using `docker-compose` to let them run together. It seems difficult to run phoenix server itself from command line. Now I can't access the docker-compose file.

Comment: Once you can share `docker-compose` file, we will be able to assist further.